# React-Router-Dom action() posting form problem

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, react-router-dom

i have a problem with posting form data to my backend . (my backend works properly with postman but it doesn't work with frontend)

here is my code's down below :

App.js

```
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import RootLayout from "./pages/RootLayout";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Event from "./pages/Event";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Contact, { action as ticketAction } from "./pages/Contact";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <RootLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Home />
      },
      {
        path: 'events',
        element: <Event />
      },
      {
        path: 'about',
        element: <About />
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        element: <Contact />,
        action: ticketAction
      }
    ]
  }
])

function App() {
  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Contact.js :

```
import { json } from 'react-router-dom'
import EventForm from '../components/Form'

const Contact = () => {
  return (
    <>

export default Contact

export async function action({ request, params }) {
  const data = await request.formData()

  const ticketData = {
    email: data.get('email'),
    name: data.get('name'),
    lastName: data.get('lastName'),
    phoneNumber: data.get('phoneNumber')
  }

  const response = fetch('http://localhost:8080/contact', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body : JSON.stringify(ticketData)
  })
}
```

Form.js:

```
import { Form } from 'react-router-dom'

const EventForm = () => {
  return (
    <Form method='post' action='/iletisim'>
      <input type={"text"} name="name" placeholder='name/>
      <input type={"text"} name="lastName" placeholder='lastName/>
      <input type={"email"} name="email" placeholder='email/>
      <input type={"tel"} name="phoneNumber" placeholder='phoneNumber/>
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </Form>
  )
}

export default EventForm;
```

my backend codes:

index.js :

```js
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080

const postingTicket = require('./mongoose') 

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/', (req,res) => { res.send('Hello World!') }) app.get(
  '/iletisim',
  (req,res) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.send('ticket') 
  }
)

app.post('/iletisim', postingTicket.buyTicket)

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(Example app listening on port ${port})
})
```

mongoose.js:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Ticket = require('./schemes/ticketSchema')

mongoose.connect(<URL GOES HERE>)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to database')
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('Connection failed')
  })

const buyTicket = async (req, res, next) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  const buyedTicket = new Ticket({
    email: req.body.email,
    name: req.body.name,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber
  });

  console.log(req.body);

  const result = buyedTicket.save()
  res.json(result)
}

exports.buyTicket = buyTicket
```

ticketSchema.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const ticketSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  phoneNumber: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Ticket', ticketSchema)
```

I expected this to work well but it has so many problems. Where am I wrong? It doesn't send anything to the backend.

Comment: The `ticketAction` action function doesn't appear to wait for the `fetch` to resolve nor return any Promise/data for the UI to receive.

Answer (score 1):

Base on your code i can make some conclusion :

1. your express accept : POST /iletisim
2. you try to communicate with your rest api by using :
   `<form method='post' action='/iletisim' >`

and so with this code... what you need to know is that the above code is not actually sending `POST` request to your backend server. rather, it will send `POST` request to your react server :)

finally, how can you send the request to your backend server>
well multiple option, but i think the easiest is to use `axios` library and do it like this

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export const Form = () => {
const [name, setName] = useState('')

const onNameChange = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value)
}

const onSubmit = async () => {
    // in second parameter, fill it with the appropriate body
    await axios.post('/iletisim', { name })
}

return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input placeholder='Name' onChange={onNameChange} value={name} />
        <button>Save</button>
    </form>
)
```

}

i hope this answer help, and feel free to ask

Comment: it didn't work too

Comment: i have same and more problem with this code

Comment: how can i implement this to my code ?